# Unique prime factors using HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I wrote a method that recursively finds prime factors. Originally, the method simply printed values. I am currently trying to add them to a `HashSet` to find the unique prime factors.

In each of my original print statements, I added a `primes.add()` in order to add that particular integer into my set.

My printed output remains the same, for example, if I put in the integer `24`, I get `2*2*2*3`. However, as soon as I print the `HashSet`, the output is simply `[2]`.

```
    public static Set<Integer> primeFactors(int n)
    {
        Set<Integer> primes = new HashSet<Integer>();

        if(n <= 1)
        {
            System.out.print(n);
            primes.add(n);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int factor = 2; factor <= n; factor++)
            {
                if(n % factor == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(factor);
                    primes.add(factor);
                    if(factor < n)
                    {
                        System.out.print('*');
                        primeFactors(n/factor);
                    }
                    return primes;
                }
            }
        }
        return primes;
    }
```

I have tried debugging via putting print statements around every line, but was unable to figure out why my `.add()` was not adding some values into my `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this by adding:

```
primes.addAll(primeFactors(n/factor));
```

Within my if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could also reduce n. A bit faster.

```
        for (int factor = 2; factor <= n; factor++)
        {
            if (n % factor == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(factor);
                primes.add(factor);
                while (n % factor == 0)
                {
                     n /= factor;
                     System.out.print('*');
                     primeFactors(n/factor);
                }
            }
        }
```

If Set `{2, 3}` needs to be a List `[2, 2, 2, 3]` the `add` needs to be done in the `while`.